# Can I use mule object store to persist HTTP Connections?

Tags: websocket, mule, server-sent-events

I have seen lot of examples of Mule Object Store being used to store transactional data. However my question is can it be used to store something like a Websockets connection or Server Sent Events(SSe) Connection?

As these are long running connections. THey need to be stored somewhere for later use when another event comes in & needs to be transmitted on the same connection. What is the best practice for storing this connection information.

Obviously connection-id can be used for as a Key and hashed form of the Connection can be stored as Value? Is this feasible? Is there an example anybody can point me to?

Comment: I'd say just use a Javascript `Map` object (or maybe a `WeakMap`) with the id as the key and the connection object as the value.  These have to be stored in-memory in Javascript so usually, you can't put them into an external store unless it happens to be an in-process memory store that can handle live Javascript objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A webSocket connection is a live object that cannot be persisted the way a simple JSON object can.  It contains pointers to an actual TCP socket internal to its implementation.  So, you need to store it in some sort of in-memory and in-process store or data structure.

Since it sounds like you already have a simple key to access it by with an ID, what I would suggest is either a `Map` or a `WeakMap` object.

```
let socketMap = new Map();
```

Any time a new socket connects:

```
// add new connection to the map
socketMap.set(id, socket);
```

Any time a socket disconnects:

```
// remove disconnected socket from the map
socketMap.delete(id);
```

Any time you need to get a particular socket:

```
let socket = socketMap.get(id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply jfriend, looks like I can rule out using the Mule Object Store as a storage mechanism for holding a Websocket or SSE Connection. In memory or In process structure like a Map seems to be the way to go . However if I exit the JVM or if Mule shutoffs I would lose those connection references. How can I persist the connections and I don't want to reopen a new one.